# Customising Azure API Management Developer Portal's user management

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management

I am trying to customize the Developer Portal in the APIM.

One thing that is important to me is user management. I want to use Azure AD B2C to handle all of my user Authentication/Authorization and remove DevPortal's own sign-in/signup section.

I could get rid of those widgets but the User profile is the issue now. My problem is not about widgets.

1. I don't see anywhere to update the user profile.
2. User info is so limited (user_name, last_name)

I want to update users from AD B2C and see that extra info in the portal. Is there any way to update user dto in the portal?

Answer (score -1):

> I want to update users from AD B2C and see that extra info in the
> portal. Is there any way to update user dto in the portal?

One of the workaround you can follow to achieve the above requirement,

*To customize the APIM developer portal by adding authentication method as Azure AD B2c we need the following perquisite first*;

- ***Create AzureAD B2c tenant***.
- ***Add user flow (Signin-signup policy)***
- ***Register an application in that tenant*** .
- ***Add secret and copy the value to use in next*** .

So, To remove the identity as username and password you can delete them as shown below;

[image]

After creating all the aforementioned perquisite now click on Add and select the identity as Azure AD B2C  and provide the required details.

For e.g;-
*Select the identity as Azure AD B2C and provide the required details*;
[image]
[image]

[image]

After done with the above steps Navigate to Developer portal and click on sign to check if the Azure AD B2C authentication is added or not.

[image]
[image]

*For more information please refer this* **Tech-community blog** |[***How to integrate Azure Active Directory B2C into Azure API Management Developer Portal***](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/how-to-integrate-azure-active-directory-b2c-into-azure-api/ba-p/2424805).

And this ;
**MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATOIN**| [***How to authorize developer accounts by using Azure Active Directory B2C in Azure API Management***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad-b2c) .

***Similarly,*** *If want to authenticate with Azure AD we can do in the same way by selecting identity provider as Azure Active directory.*

Comment: The instruction you mentioned is part of apim documentation which I checked and didn't find useful for my customization.I already know how to integrate B2C into the developer portal. My question was about how to extend the User dto to include more data and also how to update user profile after integrating AD B2C.

Comment: Could you please refer this [MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-api-management?tabs=app-reg-ga) .

Comment: I already did it before posting this question. I need to know how to extend the user and add more fields to it.

Comment: You can surely add extra user data with more fields by enabling or adding more user attributes /custom user attributes as optional claims in Azure ADB2C & accordingly call them in custom policies through user journey.  Please check this [**image**](https://i.imgur.com/UM4VMpb.png) for detail .